# Best practice for caching backend responses from front end ajax on a static website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, browser-cache

Here is my javascript code. This is just a single example, but I also have two other areas with very similar code to get data from a backend.

```
function getBalance() {
  $.ajax({
    url: ".../api/getBalance",
    type: "GET",
    crossDomain: true,
    headers: {
      Authorization: localStorage.getItem("NanoAuthToken"),
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data, code, x) {
      document.getElementById("balance").innerHTML = `${Math.round(
        data.balance * 100
      )} Nanos <br/> $${Math.round(data.balance * 100) / 100}`;
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  getBalance();
});
```

Currently, every time I refresh the browser, it will blank out all the places I put data into and wait a little before putting the data back in.

I know I could store the data in localstorage and on load retrieve this data and put it in temporarily, so the data will be there faster, but that seems like a hacky workaround. What's the proper thing to do here?

Comment: The only other way is to store the data in a database on the server.

Comment: @RobinZigmond so for clarity, you're saying the proper thing to do _would_ be to store the data in localstorage and temporarily retrieve that while waiting for the ajax call?

Comment: I don't know what the "proper" thing to do is in your application. But yes, I think it's likely better to store the data in localStorage on the client side, at least if the data there is relatively recent.